In Qt, how do you determine a file's proper encoding, and subsequently load it into a QString?
Backstory ( You can skip )

Building a sgml parser
Testing it with every html document on my computer locate *.html > /tmp/htmldump
Coming across a lot of different type of documents:

file "effects_documentation.html"
effects_documentation.html: 
HTML document, 
Unicode text, 
UTF-16, 
little-endian text, 
with CRLF line terminators


Many of the files are not being read properly for encoding, in spite of the fact that each shares the .html mime type.
This one file required me manually specifying that encoding:

QTextStream ts(&f);
ts.setEncoding(QStringConverter::Encoding::Utf16LE);  // Set encoding to UTF-16 Little Endian explicitly

QString content = ts.readAll();
f.close();


Not all files share this encoding either ( obviously )

Question:
In Qt, how can I ensure that whenever I read from a QFile, given that I expect html text, that it is encoded properly into a QString, and a QStringView for me to parse?

QStringDecoder::decoderForHtml(QByteArrayView data)
